Adding variables and values to warm start using CPLEX in C++
I have an assignment to add a warm start to C++ using CPLEX. I would like to avoid adding ~40 variables manually and automate this.
vector<IloOplElement> getAllElements(IloOplModel opl, const string& filename) {
    ifstream file(filename);
    vector<IloOplElement> elements;

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file: " << filename << endl;
        return elements;
    }

    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        if (line.empty()) continue;
        size_t pos = line.find('=');
        if (pos == string::npos) continue;
        string name = line.substr(0, pos - 1);
        elements.push_back(opl.getElement(name.c_str()));
    }

    file.close();
    return elements;
}

//rest of code in main
IloOplDataSource data(env, "...\\project.dat");
IloCplex cplexWarmStart(env);
IloOplModel oplWarmStart(def, cplexWarmStart);
oplWarmStart.addDataSource(data);
oplWarmStart.generate();

string filename = "...\\project1.dat";
vector<IloOplElement> listOfElements = getAllElements(opl, filename);
vector<IloOplElement>::iterator it;

for (it = listOfElements.begin(); it != listOfElements.end(); it++) {
    IloOplElement intVar = *it;
    IloIntMap intMap = intVar.asIntMap();
    IloIntVarMap intVarMap = intVar.asIntVarMap();
    warmStartVectors.attach(intVarMap, intMap);
}
warmStartVectors.setStart(cplexWarmStart);

The error is on for IloOplElement intVar = *it; IloIntMap intMap = intVar.asIntMap();. When I convert to IntMap, suddenly I get crash program. How can I fix it?

At https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/hybrid.mod I shared how to do that within OPL scripting
  // And warmstart CPLEX
  var vectors = new IloOplCplexVectors();
  // We attach the values (defined as data) as starting solution
  // for the variables x.
  
  for(var i=0;i<=(n+2)*(n+2)-1;i++) thisOplModel.values[i]=opl2.x[i];
  vectors.attach(opl1.x,thisOplModel.values);
  vectors.setStart(cplex);   

The full main:
// hybrid CPOptimizer and CPLEX to solve lifegame
//
// warmstart between CPO and CPLEX to use them both
// 
// the objective is maximize
//
// And in 60s
//
// we get 
// 396 hybrid (hybrid.mod)
// 379 cplex alone (lifegameip.mod)
// 280 cpo alone (lifegamecp.mod)

int nbiter=3;
int n=30;

int values[0..(n+2)*(n+2)-1];
main {

    var n=thisOplModel.n;
   var nbiter=thisOplModel.nbiter;

  var source1 = new IloOplModelSource("lifegameip.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def1 = new IloOplModelDefinition(source1);
  
  
  var source2 = new IloOplModelSource("lifegamecp.mod");
  var cp = new IloCP();
  var def2 = new IloOplModelDefinition(source2);
  
  var opl1 = new IloOplModel(def1,cplex);
  var opl2 = new IloOplModel(def2,cp);
  opl1.generate();
  opl2.generate();
  
  var objValues=new Array(2*5);
  
  for(var iter=1;iter<=nbiter;iter++)
  {
  
  writeln("iter ",iter);
  
  // start with CPLEX
  cplex.tilim=10;
  cplex.solve();
  writeln("cplex objective = ",cplex.getObjValue());
  
  objValues[iter*2-1]=cplex.getObjValue();
  
  cp.param.timelimit=10;
  
  // Warmstart in CPO
  var sol=new IloOplCPSolution();
  for(var i=0;i<=(n+2)*(n+2)-1;i++) sol.setValue(opl2.x[i],opl1.x[i]);
  cp.setStartingPoint(sol);
  
 
  // CP Solve
  cp.solve();
  writeln("cpo objective =",cp.getObjValue());
  objValues[iter*2]=cp.getObjValue();
  
  // And warmstart CPLEX
  var vectors = new IloOplCplexVectors();
  // We attach the values (defined as data) as starting solution
  // for the variables x.
  
  for(var i=0;i<=(n+2)*(n+2)-1;i++) thisOplModel.values[i]=opl2.x[i];
  vectors.attach(opl1.x,thisOplModel.values);
  vectors.setStart(cplex);   
}  
  
 writeln("list of objectives") ;
 for(var i=1;i<=2*nbiter;i++) writeln(objValues[i]);
  
}  

